# jQuery animate API triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a **rollover** image effect with the combination of image source **swaping**, **fading in/out**, and a **rotateY** animation by using **jQuery animate API**. But sometimes it produces a weird result, the animation **triggered multiple times** if the mouse cursor was **dragged (before the mouseenter animation finish)** a couple of times in the image area.

The code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("img[data-alt-src]")
    .mouseenter(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    img.finish().animate({ opacity: '-=1.0', deg: '+=90' }, {
      duration: 250,
      step: function(now) {
        img.css({
          '-moz-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-o-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-ms-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          transform: 'rotateY('+now+'deg)'
        });
      },
      complete: function() {
        img.data('tmp-src', img.attr('src'));
        img.attr('src', img.data('alt-src'));
      }
    });
    img.animate({ opacity: '+=1.0', deg: '-=90' }, {
      duration: 250,
      step: function(now) {
        img.css({
          '-moz-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-o-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-ms-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          transform: 'rotateY('+now+'deg)'
        });
      }
    });
  })
    .mouseleave(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    img.finish().animate({ opacity: '-=1.0', deg: '+=90' }, {
      duration: 250,
      step: function(now) {
        img.css({
          '-moz-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-o-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-ms-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          transform: 'rotateY('+now+'deg)'
        });
      },
      complete: function() {
        img.attr('src', img.data('tmp-src'));
      }
    });
    img.animate({ opacity: '+=1.0', deg: '-=90' }, {
      duration: 250,
      step: function(now) {
        img.css({
          '-moz-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-o-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          '-ms-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
          transform: 'rotateY('+now+'deg)'
        });
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block">
    <img
      src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
      data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
      alt="">
    <img
      src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
      data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
      alt="">
    <img
      src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
      data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
      alt="">
    <img
      src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg"
      data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg"
      alt="">
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

The output:
[image]

PS: *If I logged from console, the console also firing multiple logs in one mouseenter event.*

Any help would be appreciated. TiA.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {

  $("img[data-alt-src]").on('mouseenter', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      var img$ = $(e.currentTarget);
      if (img$.hasClass('opened')) {
        return false;
      } else {
        img$.addClass('opened');
      }
      img$.finish().animate({
        opacity: '-=1.0',
        deg: '+=90'
      }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
          img$.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
          });
        },
        complete: function() {
          img$.data('tmp-src', img$.attr('src'));
          img$.attr('src', img$.data('alt-src'));
        }
      });
      img$.animate({
        opacity: '+=1.0',
        deg: '-=90'
      }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
          img$.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
          });
        }
      });
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      var img$ = $(e.currentTarget);
      img$.removeClass('opened')
      img$.finish().animate({
        opacity: '-=1.0',
        deg: '+=90'
      }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
          img$.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
          });
        },
        complete: function() {
          img$.attr('src', img$.data('tmp-src'));
        }
      });
      img$.animate({
        opacity: '+=1.0',
        deg: '-=90'
      }, {
        duration: 250,
        step: function(now) {
          img$.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
          });
        }
      });
    });

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block">
    <img src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg" data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg" data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg" data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_1-270x270.jpg" data-alt-src="http://mcenter.lazim.org/image/cache/catalog/demo/nikon_d300_3-270x270.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Check out this :)

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you so much. Any explanation?

Comment: It seems doesn't work. Still firing multiple times.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan for me it works. What are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

You're triggering the same event too many times thus the animation is wonky. Couple of notes

1. Consider using MouseOver/Mouseout
2. Consider using addClass/removeClass for css animation code
3. Make sure the css animation ends before starting another (https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/)

Comment: I just triggering the event when the mouse entering the object and when leaving the object. Not continuously like the mouseover/mouseout do.

I can't use CSS in this case, so I just have to use pure JavaScript.